# F# TypeInitializationException Thrown Parsing Json File

Tags: f#, type-providers

Playing around with F# Type Providers and have not got too far. I have the following json file (called PriceDemand.json):

```
[
  {
    "intervalDate": "2018-01-22T00:00:00+11:00",
    "regionId": "NSW1",
    "rrp": 114.17,
    "totalDemand": 12338.04
  },
  {
    "intervalDate": "2018-01-22T00:00:00+11:00",
    "regionId": "NSW1",
    "rrp": 113.41,
    "totalDemand": 12334.98
  }
]
```

I've written the following code to process it:

```
open FSharp.Data
open System

type PriceDemand = JsonProvider<"PriceDemand.json">
let data = PriceDemand.Parse("PriceDemand.json")

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =


    data |> Seq.iter (fun v -> printf "%s" v.RegionId)

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I have intellisense for the `PriceDemand` type, but the following `TypeInitializationExceptionexception` is being thrown:

> Invalid JSON starting at character 0,
>   snippet =
>   ---- PriceDemand
>   ----- json =
>   ------ PriceDemand.json

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `.Parse` where you should be calling `.Load`.  The string `"PriceDemand.json"` is being parsed as JSON, which is not valid.  If you change the call to `let data = PriceDemand.Load("PriceDemand.json")`, it should work fine.